# select next event from database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am working on a function which selects a list of dates, and highlight the next event.  I have managed to highlight all future events, however I would like to only highlight the nearest future event.  How can this be done?

```
<?php
function racesbydate($sql) {
    include 'connect.php';
    $year = $_GET['year'];
    $get = $year.'%';
    $select = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $select->bind_param('s', $get);
    $select->execute();
    $select->store_result();
    if ($select->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<div class='races' id='$year' style='display:block'>
         <table>\n<th colspan='5'>Cycling Season $year </th>\n
                <tr id='information'>\n
                    <th id='date'>Date</th>\n
                    <th id='race'>Race</th>\n
                    <th id='route'>Route</th>\n
                    <th id='info'>Entry</th>\n
                    <th id='rizultz'>Results</th>";
        $meta = $select->result_metadata();
        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
            $params[] = &$row[$field->name];            
        }
        call_user_func_array(array($select, 'bind_result'), $params);
        while ($select->fetch()) {
            $today = date("Y-m-d");
            $date = new DateTime($row['date']);
            $formatted_date = $date->format('d/m/Y');
            if ($row['date'] > $today) {  
                if ($row['infoID'] != "0") {
                    echo "<tr class='racedetails' id='nextrace' >\n
                    <td class='dark' id='date'>".$formatted_date."</td>\n
                    <td class='light' id='race'>".$row["title"]."</td>\n
                    <td class='dark' id='route'>".$row["route"]."</td>\n
                    <td class='light' id='info'><a href='".$row["infoID"]."'>Info</a></td>\n
                    <td class='dark' id='rizults'>N/A</td>\n</tr>\n";
                }
            } else {
                if (($row['infoID'] != "0") && ($row['resultID'] !="0" )) {
                    echo "<tr class='racedetails' id='race' >\n
                    <td class='dark' id='date'>".$formatted_date."</td>\n
                    <td class='light' id='race'>".$row["title"]."</td>\n
                    <td class='dark' id='route'>".$row["route"]."</td>\n
                    <td class='light' id='info'><a href='".$row["infoID"]."'>Info</a></td>\n
                    <td class='dark' id='rizults'><a href='".$row["resultID"]."'>Results</a></td>\n</tr>\n";
                }
            }

        }
    }
    echo "</table>\n</div>";
    $select->close();
}
```

**current result**

```
<tr class='racedetails' id='nextrace' ><td class='dark' id='date'>06/01/2016</td></tr>
<tr class='racedetails' id='nextrace' ><td class='dark' id='date'>08/02/2016</td></tr>
```

**goal results**

```
<tr class='racedetails' id='nextrace' ><td class='dark' id='date'>06/01/2016</td></tr>
<tr class='racedetails' id='race' ><td class='dark' id='date'>08/02/2016</td></tr>
```

Comment: Change your condition `if ($row['date'] > $today)` to take into account whether a 'nextrace' has already been output, for instance using a boolean variable.

Comment: Can you give me further details regarding that?

Comment: So you are saying, yes that sounds good. **now do it for me** Right?

Comment: Side note. you may want to read about XSS (Cross site scripting) the variable $year is vulnerable

Comment: @RiggsFolly - not exactly, more along the lines of getting a simple example, so as I get something to work with.  :)

Comment: Create an new function with an query. Not knowing your table structure but your could be something like this `SELECT * FROM race WHERE date > '[date_today]' ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1`.. p.s make sure you index the column `date`

Comment: Would this function be a somehow a part of the other function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you only need a flag to store the information whether the next race has already been seen or not:

```
    :
    call_user_func_array(array($select, 'bind_result'), $params);
    $nextRace = true;
    while ($select->fetch()) {
        $today = date("Y-m-d");
        $date = new DateTime($row['date']);
        $formatted_date = $date->format('d/m/Y');
        if ($row['date'] > $today) {  
            if ($row['infoID'] != "0") {
                $cssId = $nextRace ? 'nextrace' : 'race';
                $nextRace = false;
                echo "<tr class='racedetails' id='".$cssId."' >\n
                <td class='dark' id='date'>".$formatted_date."</td>\n
                <td class='light' id='race'>".$row["title"]."</td>\n
                <td class='dark' id='route'>".$row["route"]."</td>\n
                <td class='light' id='info'><a href='".$row["infoID"]."'>Info</a></td>\n
                <td class='dark' id='rizults'>N/A</td>\n</tr>\n";
            }
        } else {
        :
```

This assumes that the order of the races is ascending by date (which your examples suggest).

Comment: Works almost perfectly - just needed to add the line containing $cssID in the previous line - between the if statements, and then it works perfectly. :)

Comment: Why? I thought if the race is in the past it will constantly have `id='race'`, so no need to set it there (but that makes no difference so far). However, `$nextRace = false;` has to stay inside the `if`, otherwise it will be set to `false` while processing the first race that lies in the past.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea basically, however currently '$cssId = ..' is part of if ($row['infoID']  != "0") whereas I wanted it to be part of if ($row['date'] > 'today').

Comment: But if `$row['infoID']` is zero, there won't be any output anyways. Forget that stuff about the races in the past, i did mix up code a bit.